# send data from widget to another widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, state-management, flutter-widget

I want to send data from widget to another widget, in my example i want to send some filter data from FilterScreen.dart to ShopScreen.dart
it works fine but i dont know is what i'm doing is correct?

in filter model file:

```
class FilterData with ChangeNotifier {
  bool isFreeShipping;
  bool isSomeThingElse;

  FilterData({this.isFreeShipping = false, this.isSomeThingElse = false});

  void setFreeShippingValue(bool newval) {
    isFreeShipping = newval;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setSomeThingElseValue(bool newval) {
    isSomeThingElse = newval;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

in main.dart:

```
return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => FilterData(),
      child: MaterialApp(
       .........
    )
);
```

in tabs screen:

```
class TabsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabsScreenState createState() => _TabsScreenState();
}

class _TabsScreenState extends State<TabsScreen> {
  List<Map<String, Object>> _pages;
  int _selectedPageIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pages = [
      {
        'page': ShopScreen(),
        'title': 'shop',
      },
      {
        'page': FilterScreen(),
        'title': 'filter',
      },
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  void _selectPage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedPageIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_pages[_selectedPageIndex]['title']),
      ),
      drawer: DrawerApp(),
      body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: _selectPage,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
        // type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            icon: Icon(Icons.shop),
            title: Text('Shop'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            title: Text('Filter'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

in FilterScreen.dart:

```
class FilterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FilterScreenState createState() => _FilterScreenState();
}

class _FilterScreenState extends State<FilterScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final data = Provider.of<FilterData>(context);

    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              SwitchListTile(
                  title: Text('Free Shipping'),
                  value: data.isFreeShipping,
                  subtitle: Text('get free shipping products'),
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    data.setFreeShippingValue(newValue);
                  }),
              SwitchListTile(
                  title: Text('Some thing else'),
                  value: data.isSomeThingElse,
                  subtitle: Text('get filtred products'),
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    data.setSomeThingElseValue(newValue);
                  }),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

in ShopScreen.dart:

```
class ShopScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final data = Provider.of<FilterData>(context);

    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
            data.isFreeShipping ? 'get favorite Products' : 'get all products'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9GVN.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your question indeed is a pain for most of the developers, which is like *I don't know how it works!*

So, if you are not able to understand. there are two reasons to that:

- You just blindly followed the tutorial or documentation, because of the time constraints
- You did not understand how `Flutter Provider State Management works`. So, for that, do read upon these:

  - [List of state managements in flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)
  - [Flutter provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), of course you have used that in your project. But read how he is using.

So, now let us jump to the code. **How your code works?**

There are multiple things which are responsible for this:

**1. Provider Wrap:** If you closely look into the `main.dart` code, you have done this

```
return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => FilterData(), // here you define the ChangeNotifier class
      child: MaterialApp(
       .........
    )
);
```

Now looking at the above code, you see, whenever you wrap the app with the `ChangeNotifierProvider()`, it always **rebuilds whenever there is a state change in the class which you have provided inside that**, in this case `FilterData()`. Any changes happens will reflect in the whole app, because `ChangeNotifierProvider()`, is keep rebuilding the state of the immediate child, in this case your, `MaterialApp()`, which is wrapped.

**2. NotifyChanges from the ChangeNotifier class:** If you look at your `FilterData`, it is the one which is responsible for the rebuilding of the app, which is wrapped by the `ChangeNotifierProvider()`.

Let us see how:

```
  void setFreeShippingValue(bool newval) {
    isFreeShipping = newval;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setSomeThingElseValue(bool newval) {
    isSomeThingElse = newval;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

If you closely take a look at the methods, which I mentioned in the above code from your `FilterData` class only, they have `notifyListeners()`. These are the ones, which is responsible, whenever your two methods called, it notifies the `ChangeNotifierListener` to rebuild the widget, and hence you see the updated data every time, you use any of the two methods

**3. Using NotifyListeneres method from the FilterData in FilterScreen:** So, again if we look closely at the thing which we have mentioned in the **point 2**, we see that, the method method should be called to make changes in the App which is the immediate child of `ChangeNotifierProvider()`

```
                 SwitchListTile(
                  title: Text('Free Shipping'),
                  value: data.isFreeShipping,
                  subtitle: Text('get free shipping products'),
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    data.setFreeShippingValue(newValue);
                  }),
              SwitchListTile(
                  title: Text('Some thing else'),
                  value: data.isSomeThingElse,
                  subtitle: Text('get filtred products'),
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    data.setSomeThingElseValue(newValue);
                  }),
```

So, when you call any of the methods in your `onChanged`, it straight away notifies the Provider that, the value has been changed, and the app rebuilds, and when you switch to the other tab, you see updated result like magic.

**MOST IMPORTANT:** Your `final data = Provider.of<FilterData>(context);`, is an instance of the Provider class, which trigger the method to help notify the `ChangeNotifierProvider()` to make changes in the app

So the mapping is like that:

```
                                                          Listens to the change
FilterData {setFreeShippingValue, setSomeThingElseValue} <----------------------> ChangeNotifierProvider() REBUILDS MATERIALAPP()
```